# React userReducer init function not triggering on props update

Tags: reactjs, state, reducers

I have a component which is a form which I use to create records in my database. I also want to be able to pass into this component values with which to populate the form, allowing me to then update my existing database records. Straightforward add/edit functionality from the same component.

The following code should explain how I am doing this. The `media` prop is an object containing the data. I have this data already in the parent element so setting the values here is fine and they pass thru without problem. However once the page is loaded the 3rd `init` argument of `useReducer` never re-triggers, and therefore my state cannot be overridden with the values passed down in the `media` prop. Is there a correct way to make the `init` function trigger when the props are updated, or is my issue architectural?

```
const MediaUploadForm = ({ media }) => {

  const init = (initialState) => {

    if (media) {
      // ... here I extract the values I need and override the initialState where required 
    } else {
      return initialState
    }
  }

  const [formState, dispatch] = useReducer(
    MediaFormReducer,
    initialState,
    init
  )
```

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to reinitialize your reducer state on rerender. Is media `undefined` the first time `MediaUploadForm` renders? I think you should dispatch an action when your props change

Comment: @sliptype yes that seems the better architecture. I was trying to keep this a functional component and I realise that combining useReducer with useEffects is a solution. Thank you for the push in the right direction. I will answer my own question with my solution if no one else has better answers in the next day or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So using the new React hooks features and keeping the component functional allows me to use `useEffects()` This is similar to using a `componentDidUpdate` type event. So the following code allows me to check for the status of a prop (`media`) and then dispatch an action that sets my redux state.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (media && id !== media.id) {
      dispatch(loadMedia(media))
    }

  })
```

Thanks to @sliptype for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Copying props into state is considered an anti pattern in React. Props changes do not trigger reinitialising state, as you have seen.

This is described in https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html.

From the recap it looks like the current suggested solution matches

> Alternative 1: To reset only certain state fields, watch for changes in a special property (e.g. props.userID).

This is an alternative, rather than the recommendation.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recap

Hope this link gives you more information around the topic, and the recommendations there help in future work.